# Dynamic Content inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` and I am assigning some properties like labels with the datasource. But I am also creating a control dynamically inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and then adding it to the cell. Since I am using `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:` the dynamic content gets messed up.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.stepperView.tag = [indexPath row];
    [cell.stepperView addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [[cell.calendarView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    //THIS LINE ADDS A DYNAMIC CONTENT TO THE CELL
    [self addDatePicker:cell];  

    return cell;
}


-(void) addDatePicker:(AutomaticAnnualIncreasesCell *)cell
{
    DatePicker *datePicker = [[DatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.calendarView.frame.size.width, cell.calendarView.frame.size.height)];

    datePicker.tag = 100;

    if([cell.calendarView viewWithTag:datePicker.tag] != nil)
    {
        [cell.calendarView addSubview:datePicker];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you post the code of the addDatePicker ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it implemented you'll end up with many copies of whatever content is added in `addDatePicker:`.

I would add a property to a custom cell for each dynamic content value, and in the `setSomeDynamicProperty:` method remove any existing subview and add the new one (or simply adjust the one you have).  This will prevent you from getting multiple copies of content.  Just make sure you set the property to `nil` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` if a given row doesn't need it.

Comment: I don't think that will work since when you scroll and the cells are dequed then if I remove the subviews then all the values will be gone.

Comment: You would be removing the stale views (since they applied to the cell before it was reused) and then adding fresh ones that apply to the current row.